# Pydoop installation (a classpath issue)? [SOVLED]

Tags: python, installation

I have been struggling to install pydoop. I followed the instruction on this page 
http://crs4.github.io/pydoop/installation.html.

When I ran pip install pydoop, the terminal just output a remarkable number of errors, but I could not pinpoint the main problem. I pasted some of the errors below:

```
Compiling Java classes
  src/v2/it/crs4/pydoop/pipes/Application.java:33: error: package org.apache.commons.logging does not exist
  import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
                               ^
  src/v2/it/crs4/pydoop/pipes/Application.java:34: error: package org.apache.commons.logging does not exist
  import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
                               ^
  src/v2/it/crs4/pydoop/pipes/Application.java:35: error: package org.apache.hadoop.fs does not exist
  import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
```

and

```
src/v2/it/crs4/pydoop/pipes/BinaryProtocol.java:61: error: cannot find symbol
private DataOutputBuffer buffer = new DataOutputBuffer();
        ^
symbol:   class DataOutputBuffer
location: class BinaryProtocol<K1,V1,K2,V2>
where K1,V1,K2,V2 are type-variables:
  K1 declared in class BinaryProtocol
  V1 declared in class BinaryProtocol
  K2 declared in class BinaryProtocol
  V2 declared in class BinaryProtocol
  src/v2/it/crs4/pydoop/pipes/BinaryProtocol.java:62: error: cannot find symbol
private static final Log LOG =
```

So I failed to build the wheel.

```
Failed building wheel for pydoop
  Running setup.py clean for pydoop
Failed to build pydoop
Installing collected packages: pydoop
  Running setup.py install for pydoop ... error
```

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED 
The path that the program automatically assigned is not correct. 
So set

HADOOP_HOME = /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.2/libexec